# How can I tell if used modules are pure perl?

Tags: perl, module

If I have Perl code which `use`es a lot of modules, is there a fast and easy way to find out if some of this modules are not pure Perl modules?

Comment: Why do you want to know?  What problem are you trying to detect?

Comment: That has just occurred to me in my mind, it's not a current problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@DynaLoader::dl_modules` contains the list of XS modules loaded.

```
perl -MSome::Module1 -MSome::Module2 -M... \
   -MDynaLoader -E'say for sort @DynaLoader::dl_modules;'
```

Or if you wanted to write it as a script:

```
# Usage: script Some::Module1 Some::Module2 ...

use 5.010;
use DynaLoader qw( );

while (defined($_ = shift(@ARGV))) {
   s{::}{/}g;
   $_ .= ".pm";
   require $_;
}

say for sort @DynaLoader::dl_modules;
```

Of course, nothing's stopping you from putting it in an existing script either.

```
use 5.010;
use DynaLoader qw( );
END { say for sort @DynaLoader::dl_modules; }
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it looks to me more reliable and it has the nicer output. Axeman's solution would be easier to use, but when I tried his solution with `JSON` it got an error-message: "Attempt to reload B.pm aborted".

Comment: I suppose Axeman's and this solution show me what is used and not what is needed. So for example they say with `Text::CSV` NOT Pure Perl.

Comment: Mine shows the XS modules you have used, just like you asked. No, it doesn't list Text::CSV. If you load Text::CSV, it reports Text::CSV_XS. If it reports Text::CSV, you don't have the Text::CSV that's on CPAN.

Comment: Yes, it shows the Text::CSV_XS. But I thought Text::CSV would use a pure perl version if Text::CSV_XS is not available.

Comment: @sid_com, Text::CSV doesn't actually do anything. It's a frontend for Text::CSV_XS and Text::CSV_PP. It'll use Text::CSV_XS if available, or Text::CSV_PP otherwise.

Comment: Does `JSON` behave analogously to `Text::CSV` concerning XS-Version vs PurePerl-version?

Comment: "This module converts Perl data structures to JSON and vice versa using either JSON::XS or JSON::PP."

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a job for what I call a "blowup sensor". You could just boobytrap the hooks, by putting this at the top of the first module:

```
BEGIN { 
    require Carp; #Does the stack stuff
    # Fool Perl into thinking that these are already loaded.
    @INC{ 'XSLoader.pm', 'DynaLoader.pm' } = ( 1, 1 );

    # overload boobytrapped stubs
    sub XSLoader::load        { Carp::confess( 'NOT Pure Perl!' ); }
    sub DynaLoader::bootstrap { Carp::confess( 'NOT Pure Perl!' ); }
}
```

Comment: @ikegami, Of course, that's not what the question asked, *is it*? "Is there a fast and easy way to find out if some of this modules are not pure Perl modules?" "Pure" is an absolute. If something fails to be pure "X", is doesn't really matter how many times it diverges from the constraints. Secondly, your comment about my comment isn't worth commenting on.

Comment: Lying about what he said doesn't change what he asked. Your code does not show which of his used modules are not Pure Perl. At best, it shows one.

Comment: Just a clarification: Some <=> more than 0. "Some of this [sic] modules" <=> "At least one".

Comment: I'm not sure what the gibberish you just posted means, but if you're trying to justify your code's behaviour, it's necessarily wrong. Your code finds at most one XS module. The op might have more than one. He specifically said he is dealing with many modules, and any of them could be XS modules.

Comment: Actually, he didn't ask to print anything at all, much less dying. Mine not only gives the yes/no answer he actually asked for, it also gets the actual list of XS modules which he surely needs. How is my answer flawed? Yours doesn't do either.

Answer (score -4):

If you have to try which modules in your Perl prog is not installed yet on your machine. You can do it like this:

```
use ExtUtils::Installed;
my $installed = ExtUtils::Installed->new();
my @miss;
foreach $module ($installed->modules()){
    @miss = $installed->validate($module);  
}
print join("\n", @miss);
```